How to check the length in playwright?
I have the following locator
feedbackMenuItem = () => this.page.getByTestId(/feedback-menu-item-/);

in a fixture.
How can I check the length to make sure it's 4.
I tried
await expect(this.feedbackMenuItem().length).toBe(4)

but it's giving me an error

What error?! (Presumably related to the fact that promises don't have lengths.) And why not https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-count

Did you check the docs? await expect(this.feedbackMenuItem()).toHaveCount(4)? Unless you have a good reason not use, use web first assertions.

If you're not sure what matchers are available, check the docs and see that there's .toHaveCount(). This is a web-first assertion with auto-waiting, which is almost always preferable to .toBe().
Applying that to your code gives:
await expect(this.feedbackMenuItem()).toHaveCount(4);

While you haven't provided much context, I don't generally put assertions in POMs, assuming you're using one. POMs simply encapsulate a page and the locators and actions on that page, but assertions stay in the test cases. So you might want to use something more like:
await expect(feedbackPage.feedbackMenuItem()).toHaveCount(4);

...where feedbackPage is an instance of your POM for whatever page you're testing. I'd also make feedbackMenuItem a simple getter rather than a method, and declare all locators in the constructor:
// In your POM:
class FeedbackPage {
  constructor(page) {
    this.page = page;
    this.#feedbackMenuItem = this.page.getByTestId(/feedback-menu-item-/);
  }

  get feedbackMenuItem() {
    return this.#feedbackMenuItem;
  }
}

// ...

// In your test:
it("should have 4 feedback menu items", async ({page}) => {
  const feedbackPage = new FeedbackPage(page);
  await expect(feedbackPage.feedbackMenuItem).toHaveCount(4);
});

or simply make the property public:
class FeedbackPage {
  constructor(page) {
    this.page = page;
    this.feedbackMenuItem = this.page.getByTestId(/feedback-menu-item-/);
  }
}

Using regex test ids is another code smell I'd do something about... generally, test ids should be fixed strings. But I'm getting a bit off track from your main question so I'll stop here.
